# client-server communication in Python

Tags: python, client-server

I have established a client-server communication.

The problem is that I can't send more than one message and I tried to fix it and I don't know what's wrong.

this is my code:

**The server code and client code are run in two different python windows.

server:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()                      # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname()              # Get local machine name

port = 12345                             # Reserve a port for your service.
s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host, port))                     # Bind to the port

s.listen(5)                              # Now wait for client connection.

conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Got connection from ', addr[0], '(', addr[1], ')')

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print(data.decode("utf-8"))
    if not data: 
        break
    conn.sendall(data)

conn.close() 

print('Thank you for connecting')
```

client:

```
import socket                           # Import socket module

host = socket.gethostname()          # Get local machine name
port = 12345                        # Reserve a port for your   service.
conn = socket.socket()                   # Create a socket object

conn.connect((host, port))

conn.sendall(b'Connected. Wait for data...') 

intosend = input("message to send:")
conn.sendall(bytes(intosend, 'utf-8')) 

data = conn.recv(1024)
intosend= "no"

while intosend != "quit":
    intosend = input("message to send:")
    conn.sendall(bytes(intosend, 'utf-8'))



conn.close()                                    # Close the socket when done


print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

can someone help?

Comment: where are you trying to send multiple messages? Is your intent that the client sends a series of messages to the server and the server echoes it back to the client?

Comment: As your code is written, the client program exits after sending the first message, which closes the socket connection. The server complains about that. If you want to be able to send multiple messages from the client, you'll need a looping or event structure on both the client and server side. There are good basic articles on this if you search the internet or look here https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html

Comment: @pynewbie I open two python windows, in one run the server code and in the other the client. when I establish a connection I send "hey" and after that I want to send something else but cant.

Comment: @Ron Norris I tried looping in the client side and it worked! but I get in the server side this message: ConnectionResetError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server side with a little protection added. Perhaps this is what you need? The server will continue to listen for connections after the client process finishes. Try it by starting the server, starting the client, sending a message, starting the client again and sending another message...

```
import socket
import threading
import sys

s = socket.socket()                      # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname()              # Get local machine name

port = 12345                             # Reserve a port for your service.
s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host, port))                     # Bind to the port

s.listen(5)                              # Now wait for client connection.

def processMessages(conn, addr):
    while True:
        try:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data: 
                conn.close()
            print(data.decode("utf-8"))
            conn.sendall(bytes('Thank you for connecting', 'utf-8'))
        except:
            conn.close()
            print("Connection closed by", addr)
            # Quit the thread.
            sys.exit()


while True:
    # Wait for connections
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('Got connection from ', addr[0], '(', addr[1], ')')
    # Listen for messages on this connection
    listener = threading.Thread(target=processMessages, args=(conn, addr))
    listener.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop the code on the client side that accepts the input and sends it.

This code worked for me on the client side.

```
import socket                            # Import socket module

host = socket.gethostname()              # Get local machine name
port = 12345                            # Reserve a port for your service.
conn = socket.socket()                   # Create a socket object

conn.connect((host, port))

conn.sendall(b'Connected. Wait for data...') 

while 1:

    intosend = input("message to send:")
    conn.sendall(intosend.encode('utf-8'))
    #data received back from sever
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print("Data: ", data.decode('utf-8'))
conn.close()                                   # Close the socket when done


print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Oops, I posted the server code accidentally.  Fixed.

Comment: Oh sorry, you're using Python 3.  try print("Data: ", data.decode('utf-8'))