# Socket stuck in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am trying to make server and client (I am still learning) but the server is stuck in the while loop even after he received the "exit" from the client.
what am I doing wrong?
thank you

## server

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("0.0.0.0",5511))
s.listen(1)

c, addr = s.accept()
msg = c.recv(2048).decode()
while msg != "exit":
    print(msg)
    print("still connected")
    msg = c.recv(2048).decode()
    c.settimeout(5)
c.close()
s.close()
```

## client

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("127.0.0.1",5511))

msg = input("What send to the server: ")
while msg != "exit":
    s.send(msg.encode())
    msg = input("What send to the server: ")
s.close()
```

Comment: Does it work properly when you send anything but "exit" ?

Comment: Yes, it works great.
just when i sent 'exit' it turn to loop

Comment: Did you try the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44662178/client-server-communication-in-python

Comment: I don't think "exit" can ever be sent by the client since the client closes as soon as it gets an "exit".

Comment: note that `sock.recv` returns a `False`y/empty string when the other end shuts down the socket (as the client would do when it calls `close`).  this is normally a better signal for client exit

Comment: Thank you for your help, you have any idea how should i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially posted this as a edit to rmh's answer but the edit didn't go throug till now so I post my own answer

server.py

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("127.0.0.1",5511))

msg = ""
while msg != "exit":
  msg = input("What send to the server: ")
  s.send(msg.encode())
s.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("0.0.0.0",5511))
s.listen(1)

c, addr = s.accept()
msg = c.recv(2048).decode()
while msg != "exit":
  print(msg)
  print("still connected")
  msg = c.recv(2048).decode()
  c.settimeout(5)
c.close()
s.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your `while` loop in the **client**. It doesn't execute the body if `msg == "exit"`. So if `msg` is `"exit"`, the client doesn't send anything to the server. As a result, the server doesn't receive a message and blocks on the `msg = c.recv(2048).decode()` line in the ""server"" code.

**server.py**

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("127.0.0.1",5511))

msg = ""
while msg != "exit":
  msg = input("What send to the server: ")
  s.send(msg.encode())
s.close()
```

**client.py**

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("0.0.0.0",5511))
s.listen(1)

c, addr = s.accept()
msg = c.recv(2048).decode()
while msg != "exit":
  print(msg)
  print("still connected")
  msg = c.recv(2048).decode()
  c.settimeout(5)
c.close()
s.close()
```

Comment: I figured out the solution as well, but my question is why the client was designed in such a way that it exempts itself from sending "exit" as a message to the server. If anyone has documentation, I would suggest adding to the answer above.

Comment: Thank you for your help, what is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your help,
I added new line of "s.send(msg.encode())" after the "while" and it work now.

Thank you very much!