# Connecting between computers with a socket

Tags: python, sockets, ip, port, ip-address

Is there a way to connect to another computer via their public IP using python sockets, so that you can send data?
In a similar way to which you can connect to a webpage, etc can you do something like this:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((ip, 6000))
```

I have seen examples of people using this in DOS scripts but can't seem to recreate it. All I get is timeout errors. The only time it worked was when using port 5000 and connecting to my own IP (but all other ports failed), any idea why this happened as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [client-server communication in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44662178/client-server-communication-in-python)

Comment: @Macattack No, I'm talking about using public IP addresses over the internet, not local IPs over a local network

Comment: you're likely behind a NAT, so you'd need to configure your router for port forwarding to your local ip for whatever port you want to use

Comment: usually there is problem because there are routers of your Internet Provider and routers of another person Internet Provider which try to block ports for your security and you don't  have access to these routers to change it. Only some ports can be open for internet. Other problem that another computer has to run server/socket on this port to accept your connection. And if you need to send data then other problem is to create some protocol to send data correctly. Socket is primitive object and it doesn't know if it gets all data or it has to wait for more. It doesn't know if data are correct

Comment: @Macattack Sorry if I am missunderstanding, but I read something about that and it said when running a server you need to have port forwarding since data coming in to the connection needs to know to which machine/server to go to since they don't all have seperate IPs, however when connecting with a client (supposing you are only sending information out) you don't need port forwarding since any packets leaving your network don't necessarily need to know where the packets came from within the network (and port forwarding simply ensures that data from the network is directed to a specific device)

Comment: @furas I understand the firewall will block some connections, but I saw when looking at DOS scripts that people were able to connect (through random ports, as they just looped over ports 20-some number). I understand you need a server to answer a request but what if I'm not sending any specific requests, can I not just connect to a network via sockets. And if not why can I not connect to another network, but can connect to my own?

Comment: do you means random ports on server on random ports on client side? `DOS` usually try to block web page and it has to send to port 80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS) but it can create local socket with random `port` and server will see users with different ports. OR maybe DOS send to random ports simply to try its luck and maybe one of this ports will be open on server. OR maybe DOS sends to random ports and then firewall has work to filter it and if DOS sends many requests then firewall has much more work and it can block.

Comment: Even to send data with your socket there has to be open socket on other computer to receive your data - and otehr computer has to run socket all time with command `listen()`  and accept() - and these commands already create server. You may not connect to other computer because there are many routes which may block port `6000` and when you connect to your local computer then you send directly without rotuers.

Comment: BTW: you don't connect to network but to computer or similar device - ie. server, router, switch, computer/notebook/tablet/smartfon, or even SmartTV with built-in computer.

Comment: @furas Yes I think I've kind of figured it out. I made code which went through all ports and tried to connect. When I used my own IP it found and connected to ports 80 (since I have a local apache server running) and some random ones that it probably just got lucky since the requests could be made so quickly. Then when I connected to a random website, it found ports 80 and 443, as you said since that's HTTP and HTTPS. When I tried to connect to one of my friends network, no ports were found, and same thing happened when he tried to connect to mine with the same code. Also I saw a youtube video

Comment: @furas where some guy talked about being DOSed and he said he had 3 random ports open since he was running some gaming server or something, which then meant it was possible for the hacker to connect. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @furas Yh that's just me replacing words in a slightly wrong context. Thanks again

Comment: @furas Just to confirm, does that mean if I open a port on my computer it should be able to connect to it, or do I have to have something accepting it (even after opening the port)?

Comment: if you run socket on some port with `listen()` and `accept()` then other people can access it - but only if routers between you and other user(s) don't block these port. Usually they don't block ports used by popular services/protocols - 80 (HTTP), 443 (HTTPS), 20 and 21 (TELNET), 22 (FTP). If you have local router to access internet then often it needs to change settings and `forward` this port to your computer. So it may not works without some changes in settings and sometimes it may not wokrs even with changes.

Comment: All this for your security - they block ports because you could accidenty run server with bugs and some hacker would use it to access your computer and steal passwords to bank accounts and/or your naked images, or delete your data, or it can encrypt all you data and gives you password to your data when you pay big money (usually in bitcoin) ([Ransomware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ransomware))

Comment: @furas So the person I mentioned before was able to be DOSed because when he was running his server or whatever, it had ports open which then were listening and accepting connection. And for example, I tried opening one of my ports to test it but it still wouldn't connect. Was this therefore because I wasn't running any `listen()` and `accept()` functions, since it only connects if there is a server listing (with port forwarding)?

Comment: if you only create `socket()` then you can't `receive` external connection. You can use `connect()` to connect to other computer - but other computer has to run socket with `listen()` and `acccept()` to `receive` your connection.

Comment: Like in phones - you can use my phone number to `connect` to me - but only if I `listen` (if I check if my phone is ringing) and if  I `accept` you call (if I press green button instead of red button). I can use your phone number to `connect` to you  only if you `listen` (if you check if your phone is ringing) and if you `accept` my call (if you press green button instead of red button).

Comment: @furas Yes ok, just had to confirm because when I tested with an open port at first I wasn't confused but then realised it was since I still wasn't running any `listen()` or `accept()`. So this means that when people get DOSed, either its a server since they will always have ports 80 and 443 running for HTTP and HTTPS (and maybe some others), or if it's a computer/router you do something to open ports and `listen()` + `accept()` or you get lucky the person just has something running that opens ports to listen for connections?